# Images as planes appears always in front

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, image

I am using the images as planes addon and when I add an image it always appears on top no matter how I rotate, I don't know if this is intentional but it didn't use to be like that.

I am using 2.90.1

Here are some images explaining.

Image A and B are centered in 0,0,0 and they are intersectin in the middle and are perpendicular, yet B appears on top always since I added it after A.

I add a screenshot with the bug, and a screenshot of how it should look.

And no, it is not a matter of the visibility in the viewport display, it is not x-ray, "in front" is not selected. So I solve it by deleteing the material and adding it again, which doesn't make sense.

Any clues?

How it looks
[image: How it looks]

How it should look
[image: How it should look]

Comment: Hello :). This is often because of material blend mode. Change it to Opaque or Alpha Hashed and it should work.

Comment: Thanks @JachymMichal sometimes I add many images as planes. Is there a way to do this in one go as opposed to one by one?

Comment: Well, the blend mode is set by the addon :). Feel free to ask a new question about that, it probably can be done using a script :).